# react-data-table-component ouput data in ExpandComponent

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, react-data-table-component

Hello good people on the Internet. I am using react-data-table-component library and I want to output something when a row is expanded, when the first row is expanded it should should show `this is row one` and the second `this is row two` like that but i cant figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated?
this is how the library works :

```
<DataTable
  title="Movie List"
  columns={columns}
  data={completedProducts}
  expandableRows
  expandableRowsComponent={ExpandedComponent}
  pagination
/>
```

the expandableRowsComponent props renders out what is shown on expanding in this case ExpandedComponent,which takes the data prop as a parameter

```
const ExpandedComponent =({ data }) => {
    // i would like to show the index of the current expanded row here
   
  });
};
```

how to i do it?
the row and columns work perfectlty and data is rendered out as expected

updated image with array data
[image]

I have extracted this data from a bigger api data as follows
specifically the bp_product_information array
[image]

Comment: I started to post an answer but then realized your specific question was about the expanded row INDEX. But, there can be more than one row expanded. Why do you actually want the row index? If just the data in the row is enough, I'll post my answer, that's what I initially had.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I have an array of  arrays that contain objects,,,I want to map over the main array  then map over each  of the inner arrays using the index of the current row so i can display the objects,,,The array has same length as the array provide in the data prop so the expanded component will display data relating to that already at the row. Currently when i map as said above ,the expanded rows display all objects
Data i want to show on expansion is in this format 
               [ [{...}],[{...}],[{...}],[{...}],[{...}]]

Comment: Hmm, if this were mine, I wouldn't rely on a row index like this. It sounds like you have parent/child records in that array - the parent should have a key/id, and you would be able to get the child records for it using that inside the callback. Can you give us a sample of your array, with values?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I have updated the question with the data array as requested

Comment: It's hard to copy and paste an image  =)

Comment: Where did that data come from that there is no actual parent key? Do you have control over this data? I am seeing child rows with duplicate names and whatnot which is rather odd. Without decent, consistent keys, React is going to have a hard time knowing which nodes to be updating too. It would have to update the entire tree.

Comment: okay so if you have the data for the child array in the row data that you pass along to your component, you can get away with something like this. If this works out for your needs let me know and I'll post it as an answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-paper-hswrz4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Nikki9696 hey man, thank you for your answer been struggling with this for the past 5 days certainly, didn't think of this.You can post as an answer and i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for pulling an item off `data` to display in the row where the data has child records

```
import "./styles.css";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";

const columns = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    selector: (row) => row.name
  },
  {
    name: "Species",
    selector: (row) => row.species
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Fluffy",
    species: "cat",
    hobbies: ["cleaning", "meowing", "chasing mice"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Boomer",
    species: "dog",
    hobbies: ["barking", "chewing", "eating"]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const ExpandedComponent = ({ data }) => {
    return data && data.hobbies ? (
      data.hobbies.map((item) => <div>{item}</div>)
    ) : (
      <div>no data</div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <DataTable
        title="Pet List"
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        expandableRows
        expandableRowsComponent={ExpandedComponent}
        pagination
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a link to their Storybook with more examples.
https://jbetancur.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/story/expandable-basic--basic